# loading back-reference groups "shortcut"

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I'm looking for a shortcut for loading back-reference groups using the same separator. Such a beast may not exist but it would be useful to me if it does. An example:

Starting with this string

```
:111 222 333 444 555
```

applying this pattern

```
:%s/\(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\)/\5 \4 \3 \2 \1/g
```

will give me this result

```
:555 444 333 222 111
```

What I'm looking for is something to replace the match,

```
:\(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\) \(\d\+\)
```

by giving it a pattern and a separator, and have it load as many groups as match.

```
::%s/<"\(\d\+\) ">/\5 \4 \3 \2 \1/g
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Many ways to do it!

#### Awk

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) { t = $(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1) = $i; $i = t; } print}' inpout.txt > output.txt
```

Prettier version of awk program:

```
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) {
        t = $(NF-i+1);
        $(NF-i+1) = $i;
        $i = t;
    }
    print
}
```

From inside Vim using filter, `:!`:

```
:%!awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF/2;i++) { t = $(NF-i+1); $(NF-i+1) = $i; $i = t; } print}'
```

#### Perl

From:  [Swapping an unlimited number of columns](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46275/swapping-an-unlimited-number-of-columns):

```
:%!perl -lane 'print join " ", reverse @F'
```

#### Pure Vim:

Use `split()`, `join()`, and `reverse()` to parse & reverse each line.

```
:g/^/call setline('.', join(reverse(split(getline("."), ' ')), " "))
```

For more help see:

```
:h :g
:h :call
:h setline()
:h getline()
:h join()
:h reverse()
:h split()
```